# MATLAB crashes when it reaches mxSetPr in a mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

I am writing a function within in a `mex` file which calls a `MATLAB` function. Unfortunately, when it comes to `mxSetPr`, `MATLAB` crashes and does not proceed further. Could someone kindly tell me how I can fix this?

```
void myconv2( double * Ain  , double *Aout, 
              int AnRows    , int AnCols, 
              double* kernel, int kernelnRows, int kernelnCols )
{

    mxArray *rhs[3], *lhs[1];

    rhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
    rhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
    rhs[2] = mxCreateString       ( "same" );

    mxSetPr( rhs[0], Ain    );
    mxSetM ( rhs[0], AnRows );
    mxSetN ( rhs[0], AnCols );


    mxSetPr( rhs[1], kernel      );
    mxSetM ( rhs[1], kernelnRows );
    mxSetN ( rhs[1], kernelnCols );


    mexCallMATLAB(1, lhs, 3, rhs, "conv2");
    Aout = mxGetPr( lhs[0] );

}
```

Comment: Stupid question, but did you allocate memory for `Ain` before using the pointer that references it?

Comment: Yes. `Ain` is allocated properly and has all the values stored in it.

Comment: Huh... how come you're creating two numeric matrices of size `0x0`?  I didn't even know that was possible.  What are you trying to achieve with those two empty matrices?

Comment: That's what the documentation says. They are dynamically allocated.

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know you could do that.  I learned something new today.  Maybe you should swap `mxSetM` and `mxSetN` before doing `mxSetPr`?  Shouldn't you allocate the space before assigning stuff to the `mxArray`?

Comment: Have you tried allocating them manually instead? I don't see why you don't do it that way. Alternatively, you could try first calling mxSetM and mxSetN. I'm not sure any of those will solve the problem, but give them a try.

Comment: @rayryeng  It's like doing `x=[]` in MATLAB, but you have to do it to create a `mxArray` container with no buffer to worry about deallocating before `mxSetPr`.  The only issue here is that the pointer assigned must have been allocate on the MATLAB memory space with `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`.

Comment: @chappjc - BAH... I should have known that.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory passed to `mxSetPr` must be allocated with `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`, NOT with `malloc`, `new`, etc.  From the [`mxSetPr` docs page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetpr.html#bqvozb3-3):

> `void mxSetPr(mxArray *pm, double *pr);`
> ...
> `pr`
>
> Pointer to the first element of an array. Each element in the array contains the real component of a value. The array must be in dynamic memory; **call `mxCalloc` to allocate this memory. Do not use the ANSI® C `calloc` function, which can cause memory alignment issues leading to program termination**. If `pr` points to static memory, memory leaks and other memory errors can result.

Another issues is with your declaration for `myconv2`, where the output argument is `double *Aout`.  Inside the function, `Aout` itself is modified, not whatever `Aout` originally points to, if anything.  To modify the pointer, either pass by reference (`double *&Aout`), or pass a double pointer (`double **Aout`) and change your calling convention.  Its easiest to use a reference if you are compiling as C++.

This will get you past the `mxSetPr` commands and allow you to run `mexCallMATLAB`, but the next issue is that the `mxArray` pointed to by `plhs[1]` is created *inside `myconv2`*, which means it will be deallocated by the MATLAB memory manager whenever it likes after the program termination.  You should either copy the data out of `lhs[1]` and into `Aout` (I think this is what you want since you pass the pointer by value) or allocate `Aout` outside of `myconv2` with `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`.

Another fun surprise with having `mxSetPr` in a different function from the one that created the `mxArray*` being assigned is that when `myconv2` exists, MATLAB will also try to destroy each `mxArray` in `rhs[]`.  Assuming you want the caller to be responsible for these arrays, then set the pointers to `NULL` before `myconv2` exits.  I've never had come across this situation before, but this might be a valid approach.

---

Copying the data inside `myconv`

```
#include "mex.h"

void myconv2(double * Ain, double *Aout,
    int AnRows, int AnCols,
    double* kern, int kernelnRows, int kernelnCols)
{
    mxArray *rhs[3], *lhs[1];

    rhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    rhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    rhs[2] = mxCreateString("same");

    mxSetPr(rhs[0], Ain);
    mxSetM(rhs[0], AnRows);
    mxSetN(rhs[0], AnCols);

    mxSetPr(rhs[1], kern);
    mxSetM(rhs[1], kernelnRows);
    mxSetN(rhs[1], kernelnCols);

    mexCallMATLAB(1, lhs, 3, rhs, "conv2");

    // prevent `Ain` and `kern` from being destroyed on `myconv2` return
    mxSetPr(rhs[0], NULL); mxSetPr(rhs[1], NULL);

    // copy each element of output
    double *d = mxGetPr(lhs[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < AnRows*AnCols; ++i)
        Aout[i] = d[i];

}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int nrows = 256, ncols = 256;
    double *Aout = new double[nrows * ncols];

    // allocate with `mxMalloc`
    double *Ain = (double*)mxMalloc(nrows * ncols * sizeof(double));
    double *kern = (double*)mxMalloc(5 * 5 * sizeof(double));

    myconv2(Ain, Aout, nrows, ncols, kern, 5, 5);

    // free here, not in `myconv2`
    mxFree(Ain);
    mxFree(kern);

    // do something with Aout
    mexPrintf("%p\n", Aout);

    delete[] Aout;
}
```

---

Creating `lhs` outside of `myconv2` to avoid any copies

```
void myconv2(double *Ain, mxArray *&lhs, int AnRows, int AnCols,
    double *kern, int kernelnRows, int kernelnCols)
{
    mxArray *rhs[3];

    rhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    rhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    rhs[2] = mxCreateString("same");

    mxSetPr(rhs[0], Ain);
    mxSetM(rhs[0], AnRows);
    mxSetN(rhs[0], AnCols);

    mxSetPr(rhs[1], kern);
    mxSetM(rhs[1], kernelnRows);
    mxSetN(rhs[1], kernelnCols);

    mexCallMATLAB(1, &lhs, 3, rhs, "conv2");

    mxSetPr(rhs[0], NULL); mxSetPr(rhs[1], NULL);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxArray *AoutMX;

    int nrows = 256, ncols = 256;
    double *Ain = (double*)mxMalloc(nrows * ncols * sizeof(double));
    double *kern = (double*)mxMalloc(5 * 5 * sizeof(double));

    myconv2(Ain, AoutMX, nrows, ncols, kern, 5, 5);

    mxFree(Ain); mxFree(kern);

    // do something with AoutMX
    mexPrintf("%x\n", mxGetPr(AoutMX));    
}
```

Although, it's important to note that when you call `conv2`, it always creates a **new `mxArray`, even if you use the same `mxArray*`**.

---

For completeness, it is worth noting that there are low-level hacks that let you assign any pointer (not just those created with `mxMalloc` and `mxCalloc`), but these involve guessing the structure of the opaque type `mxArray` and doing something like ths:

```
// effectively, mxSetPr(mxmat, Pr + n); 
((mxArray_type_guess*)(mxmat))->data.number_array.pdata = (Pr + n);
```

See the [InplaceArray FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24576-inplacearray--a-semi-pointer-package-for-matlab) for more info.  The `mxArray` struct guesses are probably badly out of date though.  Supposedly you can determine the right structure with [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23576-min-max-selection/content/MinMaxSelection/buildInternal_mxArrayDef.m).

Comment: This is a great point. I actually allocated the memory by `mxMalloc((nElem)*sizeof(double))`. However, I had to cast it to pointer of type double as `(double*) mxMalloc((nElem)*sizeof(double))` because if I take out `(double*)` the compiler will complain that `mymex.cpp(211) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double *' 
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast`. For me, it only works when I put `(double*)` in front of it.

Comment: @A2009 You do need that cast, as it returns a `void*`.  I just pasted some test code.  Perhaps it helps clarify.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the last copy (where `d` is copied to `Aout`). Unfortunately, the function `myconv2` will be called million times in my code and this copying will be very costly. May I have your thoughts?

Comment: Can I allocate `Aout` by `mxMalloc`?

Comment: @A2009 The other option I note in the answer is to pass `Aout` by reference (`double *&Aout`) and allocate `Aout` outside of `myconv2` with `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`.

Comment: @A2009 See the update.  Go with the second option, passing a `mxArray*&` into `myconv2` so that there are no copies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65395/discussion-between-a2009-and-chappjc).